# Want to assign language variable on GoogleTranslate startup

Tags: javascript, variables, translate

I'm using PHP and trying to assign a starting language variable ($lang) to Google Translate based on the country the visitor is coming from.  Here is my code

```
<?php 
  if ($_SESSION['geoCountryName']=="France") {
      $userLang = "fr";
  }
?>
<script>
/* example .. someone visiting from France */
var lang = "<?php echo $userLang; ?>";
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: lang,
    includedLanguages: 'af,ar,bg,ca,cs,cy,da,de,en,es,et,eu,fi,fr,ru',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
```

When testing and setting $lang to any language other than 'en', the function fails and renders the page in english.  Can anyone help me on my javascript syntax??  How can I set 'pageLanguage:' to a variable (exp: fr, en, de, etc)?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What's the error you get when running this code?

Answer (score 0):

`pageLanguage` is the language of the page (original).

It's not the language that you want the page be translated to.

You can indicate desired translation languages using `includedLanguages`.

So, I think that your `lang` variable is set successfully, that's why it can't translate your EN page when you ask it to translate it from FR, for example.